# append a select box with same option but different name

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I append a select box with same option and different name.
I have a loop, where my php reads a sql table, and for each row, it creates a option tag

this is the function to append:

```
$(function(){
    $('#add').click(function(){
        var select = $('span[id=combo]').html();
        $('#allCombo').append('<br/><span id="combo">'+select+'</span>');
    });
});
```

this is the select box:

```
<span id="allCombo">
                <span id="combo" name="combo">
                    <select name="item">
                        <?php foreach ($items as $item) { ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $item->item_id; ?>">
                            <?php echo $item->item_name; ?></option>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </select>
                </span>
</span>
```

Can anyone help me.
thanks before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `item[]` as name . PHP will convert this to an array, so the selected values are in an array stored at `$_POST['item']`.

But more important is to not duplicate IDs. I suggest to remove the inner `span` completely, as

1. you cannot have duplicate IDs and
2. `span` tags have no `name` attribute

so there is no need to keep this tag.

```
<span id="allCombo">
    <select name="item[]">
        <?php foreach ($items as $item): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $item->item_id; ?>">
                <?php echo $item->item_name; ?>
            </option>
       <?php endforeach; ?>
     </select>
</span>
```

The JS code would be:

```
$(function(){
    $('#add').click(function(){
        $('#allCombo')
           .append('<br />')
           .append($('#allCombo select').first().clone());
    });
});
```

Comment: I have another problem 
Can you help me please
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789219/showing-a-combo-box-by-change-value-of-another-combo-box

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    $('#add').click(function(){
        var select = $('#combo').html();
        $('<br/><span id="combo">'+select+'</span>').appendTo('#allCombo').find.('select').attr('name', 'uniqueName');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var newSelect = $('select[name=item]').clone().attr('name', 'newselect');
$('#allCombo').append(newSelect);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the clone method:

```
var new_combo $('span#combo').clone();
new_combo.attr('name', 'second_combo');
new_combo.attr('id', 'second_combo'); // for valid html
$('#allCombo').append(new_combo);
```